# RaspberryPi: Where will it belong?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been really looking forward to the release of the super-micro-super-cheap-ARM-computer [RaspberryPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) and one of my questions is "where will I get help!?"

I love StackExchange, so where exactly could I ask questions? I know that it of course depends on the questions but where do these end up going?

Examples:

1. How to install X Linux distribution on RaspberryPi. SuperUser, Unix, or neither?
2. How to do [electrical mod] on RaspberryPi. Electronics or none?

I'm sure there are a few others I could think of, but basically it boils down to should we treat the RaspberryPi like a device or like a PC? Or should we just create a raspberrypi.stackexchange? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a Raspberry-Pi proposal in Area51

To support, define (or close) this proposal, you can [go here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37041/raspberry-pi-hardware-and-software?referrer=XCWIBNXW4MLdMlwCbl6l_Q2).

Comment: Damn you even beat me to the Raspberry Pi forums!

Comment: Oops - sorry.  Thanks for supporting though.  Lots of users to go.

Answer (score 4):

For hardware questions, you could use the [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site.

For software questions, it depends.  They'll go on the site that they would best fit on now, which could be [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

If you want a RaspberryPi Stack Exchange, then you should create one and generate interest at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Super User should be fine in this case, as long as you're using the Raspberry Pi like a "real" computer. The only question is if you'll get answers, but we'll see about that.